# Merton's jump diffusion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, jump-diffusion

Can someone help me finding the expected value of the solution to Merton's jump diffusion model:

\begin{align}
S_t &= S_0 \exp \left( \left(r -  \frac{\sigma^2}{2} - \lambda k \right) t + \sigma W_t \right)  \prod_{j=1}^{N_t} (1+\epsilon_i)
\end{align}

where $W_t$ is a BM and $N_t$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ and $k$ is the expectation of $\epsilon_i$. The Brownian Motion and Poisson Process are independent.

I know that

\begin{align}
E \left[ \exp \left( \left(r -  \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right) t + \sigma W_t \right) \right] = \exp(rt)
\end{align}

but what is

\begin{align}
E \left[ \prod_{j=1}^{N_t} (1+\epsilon_i) \right] = ?
\end{align}

Comment: The product of $N_t$ factors.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: For a given sample $\omega$, $N_t(\omega)$ is an integer.

Comment: **Hint**: you can leverage the [law of iterated expectations (or total expectations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) to deal with the random variable $N_t$.

Comment: So if I condition on the number of jumps to be n then there will be n terms in the product and since each jump is independent the expectation will become $(1+k)^n$ ? I know that I am supposed to get $\exp(\lambda k t)$ but how can I get that from $(1+k)^n$ ?

Comment: Well then it's only an expectation computation, using the definition of expectation.

Comment: This question might be a duplicate of [Risk neutral measure for jump processes](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10992/risk-neutral-measure-for-jump-processes?rq=1), by the way $-$ or at least the answer to that question also answers this one.

Comment: It's never been clear where -lambda*k  comes from in the stochastic differential equation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given for all $i$ the mean of $\epsilon_i$ is $k$ and that the $\{\epsilon_i\}_i$ are i.i.d., we have$^{\text{(1)}}$:

$$\begin{align}
E\left[\prod_{i=1}^{N_t}(1+\epsilon_i)\right] &=E\left[E\left[\prod_{i=1}^{N_t}(1+\epsilon_i)|N_t\right]\right]
\\[6pt]
&=E\left[\prod_{i=1}^{N_t}E\left[(1+\epsilon_i)|N_t\right]\right]
\\[6pt]
&=E\left[\prod_{i=1}^{N_t}(1+k)\right]
\\[13pt]
&= E\left[(1+k)^{N_t}\right]
\end{align}$$

By definition of the expectation and the distributional properties of $N_t$:

$$\begin{align}
E\left[(1+k)^{N_t}\right]&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+k)^{n}\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}
\\[6pt]
&= e^{k\lambda t}
\end{align}$$

$\text{(1)}$ *Note a subtlety here that got me momentarily confused: the product of $n$ i.d.d. random variables $\epsilon_1,\cdots,\epsilon_n$ with same distribution as $\epsilon$ is **not** the same as the $\text{n}^{\text{th}}$ power of variable $\epsilon$. Hence, you cannot directly collapse the product $\prod_{1\leq i \leq n}(1+\epsilon_i)$ to the power $(1+\epsilon)^n$, you first need to "inject" the expectation into the product.*